# Extract value from string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I want to handle 2 cases:

1. `(string)` -> `string`
2. `@string otherStuff` -> `string`

how can it be done?

Comment: "What have you tried?" Did it work? If not, why not?

Comment: why was this downgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

def getstring(string):
    testforstring = re.search("\((.*)\)",string)
    if testforstring:
        return testforstring.group(1)
    testforstring = re.search("@(.*?)\s+.*",string)
    if testforstring:
        return testforstring.group(1)
    return None
```

Allows you to do:

```
>>> print getstring('(hello)')
hello
>>> print getstring('@hello sdfdsf')
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.search(r'\(([^)]+)\)|@([^ ]+) ', '(string)').groups()
('string', None)
>>> re.search(r'\(([^)]+)\)|@([^ ]+) ', '@string otherStuff').groups()
(None, 'string')
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
In [45]: s='(string)' 
In [46]: s = s[1:-1]

In [47]: s
Out[47]: 'string'
```

and

```
In [48]: s = '@string otherstuff'
In [49]: s=' '.join(s.split()[1:])  

In [50]: s
Out[51]: 'otherstuff'
```